# How can column labels/descriptions be set in R using values from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, sas, r-haven

I often work with SAS datasets which tend to come with descriptions/labels for each column, visible when using the `View()` function (they appear as subtext under each column name).

My questions has two parts: 1) how can one set those labels manually? and 2) can those labels be set using values present in a tibble?

For example, let's say I have the following dataset (which is extremely similar to one I just actually received):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(SBJID = c("Subject ID", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
             AGBL = c("Age at baseline", 54, 23, 18, 29, 31),
             LBCD = c("Parameter code", rep("HGB", 5)),
             LBRSSTDU = c("Result in standard units", 10, 12, 9, 14, 11))
```

| SBJID | AGBL | LBCD | LBRSSTDU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Subject ID | Age at baseline | Parameter code | Result in standard units |
| 1 | 54 | HGB | 10 |
| 2 | 23 | HGB | 12 |
| 3 | 18 | HGB | 9 |
| 4 | 29 | HGB | 14 |
| 5 | 31 | HGB | 11 |

I obviously don't want the first row to remain, I want to remove that row and set the values to be the descriptions for the column heads (again, as one would see from a SAS-derived data frame).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the `labelled` package as below

manual approach

```r
library(labelled)

df2 <- labelled::set_variable_labels(df, SBJID="Subject ID",
                              AGBL="Age at baseline",
                              LBCD="Parameter code",
                              LBRSSTDU="Result in standard units") %>% 
  filter(row_number()!=1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

tibble approach

```r
library(labelled)

# get the names of the variables 
nam <- names(df)

# get the labels from the first row of the tibble
lab <- paste(df[!str_detect(df$SBJID,'\\d'),],sep='#')

# create a tibble with name and label 
description <- tibble(name=nam, label=lab)

# set names to the labels 
var_labels <- setNames(as.list(description$label), description$name)

# set the labels with var_labels 
df_labelled <- df %>%
  set_variable_labels(.labels = var_labels, .strict = FALSE) %>% filter(row_number()!=1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

Comment: I took the screenshot of the dataframe by snipping tool and pasted

Comment: it is the screenshot of `df_labelled` dataframe

Comment: If I type df_labelled into the R console on Windows it does not result in that.  The labels are not shown.

Comment: view(df_labelled) may work

Comment: Rstudio i am using

Comment: I think you need to add to the answer how you generated the image and that it only works in RStudio but not in R otherwise.

Comment: ok sure i will update